# How to find uncommon data from single table without using NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like below where two rows having multiple data and some of them are common.So i want to fetch the data which not common in both rows.

Example.

```
Table Demo :
|--T1---------T2----|   
| 100003 | 110000   |
| 100003 | 120000   |
| 100003 | 130000   | 
| 100003 | 140000   |
| 100003 | 150000   |
| 100004 | 110000   |
| 100004 | 120000   |
| 100004 | 160000   |
| 100004 | 170000   |
| 100004 | 180000   |
|-------------------|

Result Set :
|--T1---------T2----|       
| 100003 | 130000   | 
| 100003 | 140000   |
| 100003 | 150000   |
| 100004 | 160000   |
| 100004 | 170000   |
| 100004 | 180000   |
|-------------------|
```

Result should remove common value from both of rows i.e 110000,120000.

I have done it using NOT IN. But i want it to do without using NOT IN.

Below is my query.

```
 Select distinct T2 
 from Demo 
 where T1 IN ('100003','100004') 
   AND T2 NOT IN (select distinct X.T2 
                  from Demo X
                    inner join Demo Y 
                             ON X.T2 = Y.T2 
                            AND X.T1='100003' 
                            AND Y.T2 ='100004');
```

Note :We can do it using intersect but It is hitting performance So i can't afford it.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without 'NOT IN' ?

Comment: Try to look at answers, upvote and accept the best one:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `COUNT` analytic function:

```
SELECT T1,
       T2
FROM   (
  SELECT T1,
         T2,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY T2 ) AS num
  FROM   demo
)
WHERE  num = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
select max(t1), t2 
from table
group by t2
having count(*) = 1;
```

in this case I used max(t1) to show it but the value is in any case unique (`count(*) = 1`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by self join after deduping.

```
WITH demo (t1,t2) AS 
(SELECT 100003 , 110000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100003 , 120000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100003 , 130000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100003 , 140000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100003 , 150000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100004 , 110000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100004 , 120000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100004 , 160000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100004 , 170000   UNION ALL
SELECT 100004 , 180000   )
SELECT a.t1,a.t2
FROM demo a
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2, COUNT(*) cnt FROM demo GROUP BY t2 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) b
ON a.t2 = b.t2;

T1     |T2    
100004 |160000
100003 |140000
100003 |150000
100004 |180000
100003 |130000
100004 |170000
```

Answer (score 0):

First find t2 values which are repeating and avoid them from result.

```
SELECT * FROM Demo WHERE T2 NOT IN 
(SELECT T2 FROM Demo GROUP BY  T2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @jophab.  I can not use NOT In because i have huge set of data.it will take much time to fetch result.

Comment: Will there be significant  difference in performance ?. I doubt

Comment: yes i have tested.it's taking 10 sec for 2 million data.

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` in the sub-query is useless, but I think Oracle ignores that anyway.

The join inside the sub-query is not needed however and will slow down the NOT in evaluation:

```
Select distinct T2 
from Demo x1
where T1 IN ('100003','100004') 
  AND T2 NOT IN (select X2.T2 
                 from Demo X2
                 where X1.T1 = X2.t1);
```

Another option is to use a NOT EXISTS instead:

```
Select distinct T2 
from Demo x1
where T1 IN ('100003','100004') 
  AND not exists (select *
                  from Demo X2
                  where X1.T1 = X2.t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Analytic-Functions.htm) variation of `count` to retrieve a count of rows with the current `t2` value for each row, then filter to those rows with a count of 1 (i.e., that particular value of `t2` only occurs once).

```
SELECT t1, t2
FROM (SELECT t1, t2, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t2) t2_count
      FROM Demo) t
WHERE t2_count = 1;
```

Here, `count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t2)` returns the count of rows with the current value of `t2`. The inner query would return

```
|--T1---------T2------T2_COUNT-|
| 100003 | 110000   | 2        |
| 100003 | 120000   | 2        |
| 100003 | 130000   | 1        | 
| 100003 | 140000   | 1        | 
| 100003 | 150000   | 1        | 
| 100004 | 110000   | 2        |
| 100004 | 120000   | 2        |
| 100004 | 160000   | 1        | 
| 100004 | 170000   | 1        | 
| 100004 | 180000   | 1        | 
|------------------------------|
```

which the outer query would then filter to your desired result set.

Comment: Please add explanation

Comment: @AndyG Explanation added.